# How to plot from raster?

Tags: r

I have three rasters:

```
 library (raster)
 r <- raster(nrows=10, ncols=10); r <- setValues(r, 1:ncell(r))
 r1 <- raster(nrows=10, ncols=10);r1 <- setValues(r1, 1:ncell(r))
 r2 <- raster(nrows=10, ncols=10);r2 <- setValues(r1, 1:ncell(r))
 st1=stack(r,r1,r2)
```

getvalues row 6 and col 5 for all rasters

```
> st1[6,5,]
   layer.1 layer.2 layer.3
[1,]      55      55      55
```

I tried to plot this as time series but the plot was not correct:

```
    plot(st1[6,5,])
```

Comment: Which package defines the `raster()` function? Could you please make the example reproducible? (That said, try `plot(st1[6,5,, drop = FALSE])` or similar.)

Comment: Thanks Krlmlr, I meant a time series not images

Comment: Coerce `st1[...]` to a vector using `as.vector()`. Not sure how you obtain a time series from this, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not clear what you want to achieve. But you can plot like this:

```
time <- as.Date(Sys.time())+1:3
plot(time, st1[6,5])
```

Or

```
s <- ts(as.vector(st1[6,5]))
plot(s)
```